# How to get the Firebase Realtime Database value to String in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all the "title"'s value to String in android. I mean I want to show all "title"'s value in "titleSet"("test01" and "20190919 test0.."). How can I get them?
[image]

This is the activity class that shows the data in recyclerView :

```
private void showData() {
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Room").child("titleSet");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<LibraryModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions
            .Builder<LibraryModel>()
            .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<LibraryModel>() {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public LibraryModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    return new LibraryModel(snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString());
                }
            }).build();

    mAdapter = new LibraryAdapter(options, context);
}
```

Is there any way to get the "title"'s value to String??

Comment: I post the LibraryActivity that will show the data.

Comment: Check out my answer and see if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to get a reference from your database.

```
 Firebase Database firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 DatabaseReference myReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("room");


    myReference.child("titleSet").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    TitleSet title = dataSnapshot1.getValue(TitleSet.class); //your Object

                    String myTitle = title.getTitle();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Titles: "+myTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                //set your adapter here

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

You an also check out this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) to know more about Retrieving data in Firebase.

Comment: Thank you!! It works well:) Thank you for your help